# Sending different message to different screens from a server using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have multiple screens connected to a single CPU. What I want to do is send different messages to each of these screen(s) simultaneously.

For ex:

Screen 1 shows "Proceed to Aisle 1"

Screen 2 shows "Proceed to Aisle 2"

and so on.

Is it possible to achieve something like this and if yes how?

Comment: You are not asking anything.

Comment: You should take a look at https://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña I just updated It. I am looking for a way to achieve what I stated using C#. I want to know if it's possible and how

Comment: The answer to your question is _yes_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain access to other screens attached to the computer by looking at the System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens array. This contains a list of all screens attached to the system and gives information about each one.
Each screens is used by certain offsets given to the top corner of the screen. If only one screen is attached, the upper left corner is (0,0). If you have a second screen attached to the right of a 1920x1080 screen then the second screen's upper left corner will be (1920,0). 
As an example, this can be used to display a form in the top left corner of the last screen:

```
        int lastScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length - 1;
        System.Windows.Forms.Screen scr = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[lastScreen];
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        f.Location = scr.WorkingArea.Location;
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.Show();
```

Again, here's quick code that will display a form on each screen with a label stating the screen number of that screen:

```
        for (int count = 0; count < System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length; count++)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen scr = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[count];
            System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            f.Location = scr.WorkingArea.Location;
            f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Label screenNumber = new Label();
            screenNumber.Text = "You are looking at screen # " + count.ToString();
            screenNumber.AutoSize = true;
            f.Controls.Add(screenNumber);
            f.Show();
        }
```

This should give you a head start on what you want to do.